# how to return an IList with members of an arbitrary type

Tags: c#, generics

I'm not sure this is even possible, but here goes: I have a class `Zoo` which holds a dictionary of Animal Type -> List of Animals. e.g.

```
Cat Type -> {Cat1, Cat2}
Zebra Type -> {Zebra1, Zebra2}
```

`Cat` and `Zebra` are subclasses of `Animal`. Now `Zoo` has a method `IList<Animal>` `GetAnimalsOfType(Type type)`.

I'd like the return value to be of the type of the animal requested, so instead of getting an `IList<Animal>` I'd get an `IList<Cat>` or an `IList<Zebra>` depending on the type of animal I passed in the type parameter.

Is this possible? If so how?

Comment: I'd try to do this without casting, using covariance. A related (but a bit confusing) question from another user: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259104/ilist-using-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-is-this-possible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, something like this is certainly possible using generics. I think you're looking for this:

```
IList<T> GetAnimalsOfType<T>() where T : Animal {
    return dictionary[typeof(T)].OfType<T>().ToList();
}
```

There's a difference between this and what you mentioned in the question. The type is *not* passed as an argument. Since the argument is passed at runtime, it doesn't make sense if it returns an strongly typed list. The compiler wouldn't know anyway and you wouldn't be able to use it.

Comment: +1, I think you may win an award for "most valid uses of T in 2 lines of code"

Comment: @JaredPar: If there's such an award, I'll change the `ToList()` call to `ToList<T>()`

Comment: @Mehrdad, but then you wouldn't be maximizing type inference and hence invalidating your badge :)

Comment: @JaredPar: The badge requirement didn't say anything about type inference maximization. Just noticed it's funny to read the code aloud!

Comment: Thanks! But then how do I call it if I want to get all Zebras for example? I can do GetLinksOfType<Zebra>() if I know the type beforehand but what if it's in a variable? I can't do GetLinksOfType<animal.GetType()>();

Comment: @Johnny: No, you can't do that. The point is, as I mentioned in the answer, the compiler would be clueless about the type `animal.GetType` and hence the return type of the function and therefore, wouldn't allow you to call any specific methods for that type. Therefore, there's not a point in doing so. In fact, you *can* call `GetLinksOfType<animal.GetType()>` with reflection but the what  do you want to do with it? You'll probably have handle each type using a specific code path (switch on the type), in which case, you'd just switch on `animal.GetType()` and call the appropriate method.

Comment: I see. So how does LINQ work that magic? If I query a list of ints I get back an IEnumerable<int>. So it seems LINQ at least is able to return an IEnumerable of whichever type the collection elements were of.

Comment: @Johnny: That's purely a compile-time thing. The compiler sees the **static** type of the variable to be `List<int>`, for instance and infers the return type. The very same compiler is not able to query `object o = thatListYouJustQueried; var l = from i in o where i > 10 select i;` because the static type of the variable is no longer `List<int>`.

Comment: @Johnny:  To summarize, the answer to your question: "I can do GetLinksOfType<Zebra>() if I know the type beforehand but what if it's in a variable?" is that, in such a case, the return type will also *naturally* **vary**. --- and since C# (3.0) is a statically typed language, the problem is where you'd want to store the return type. C# does not support variables with "varying" types. I hope I could make it clear. This might make more sense in dynamic languages like Pyhton but not in C#. If you tell us what you would want to do with the returned value, we probably can propose a solution.

Comment: Thanks again. I have to say I didn't completely understand this. If you still have patience: with your original answer I can do GetLinksOfType<Zebra>(), but I don't understand why I wouldn't be able to do Zebra zebra = new Zebra(); 
GetLinksOfType<zebra.GetType()>();

Aren't the two calls to GetLinksOfType identical? The method gets called each time with the type Zebra.

Comment: @Mehrdad: what I want to do is ask for a list of animals and then be able to work on that list knowing exactly what type of animals are in the list and without having to cast the animals into the specific animal type before using the list. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Johnny: `zebra.GetType()` is a **value** of type Type, not a type expression. It's not known until runtime what that value will be. It could be a `typeof(Zebra)` or `typeof(SomeKindOfZebra)` or anything like that. The type of the return value would **depend** on the type of that expression. The difference is that in the second case, the C# compiler does not know what the type of return value is **at compile time**. As a consequence, it would not be able to check whether `IList<Zebra> t = GetLinksOfType<zebraObject.GetType()>()` is a valid expression or not. Therefore, it's disallowed.

Comment: @Johnny: That's exactly what I wanted to hear. If you don't cast the object to a specific animal, and you call a method specific to `Zebra` (and doesn't exist in `Cat`), how would the compiler ensure its existence? Do you want to stick with members inherited from `Animal`?

Comment: Oh! Now I understand. Thanks a lot and I appreciate your patience.

Comment: Yes, I see your point, that would really break the code. I was thinking about it from the point of view of getting the animal list into a separate class and so *I* would know it's type. But obviously the compiler can't assume what it would be.

Comment: @Johnny: In fact, this *could* make sense in C# 4.0 by storing the value in a `dynamic` variable. However, the **syntax** is not provided to pass a `Type` variable as a type parameter. You can, indeed, invoke the generic method with a variable type with Reflection and save the value in a `dynamic` type and use it like any `dynamic` value in C# 4.0.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a generic method. It goes something like this:

```
public IList<T> GetAnimals<T>(){
    return this.animals[typeof(T)].Cast<T>().ToList();
}
```