# Cannot add object to list

Tags: c#, oop, interface

I'm trying out an example of using `Domain Events` to notify of when something has happened in a system (borrowed from [here](http://simon-says-architecture.com/tag/domain-events/) and [here](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/06/14/domain-events-salvation/)).

I'm really close to getting the code working how I want, however, I've hit a bit of a brick wall. Here is my `DomainEvents` class:

```
 public static class DomainEvents
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static IList<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>> Actions;

        public static void Register<T>(IEventHandler<T> callback) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            if (Actions == null)
            {
                Actions = new List<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>>();
            }

            Actions.Add(callback); // <---- Problem here, since I can't add callback to the collection.
        }

        public static void ClearCallbacks()
        {
            Actions = null;
        }

        public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            if (Actions == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (var action in Actions)
            {
                if (action is IEventHandler<T>)
                {
                    ((IEventHandler<T>)action).Handle(args);
                }
            }
        }
```

The above won't compile because `Actions.Add` cannot accept `callback` since it's a `IEventHandler<T>` type rather then a `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>` type. Here's some more code to clarify.

This is called from my console application:

`DomainEvents.Register(new CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler());`

`CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler` implements `IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>`, where `CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent` implements `IDomainEvent`.

```
public class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler : IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>
    {
        public IEmailSender EmailSender { get; set; }

        public void Handle(CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent @event)
        {
            this.EmailSender.SendEmail(@event.Customer.EmailAddress);
        }
    }

public class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        public CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent(Customer customer)
        {
            this.Customer = customer;
        }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
```

This is what I don't get - if `CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent` implements `IDomainEvent`, then why is the call to `Actions.Add` failing? How can I resolve this?

EDIT:

To make things clearer, here is entire code for my test app:

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            DomainEvents.Register(new CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler());

            var c = new Customer();

            c.EmailAddress = "test@dfsdf.com";

            c.CheckUnpaidDues();
        }
    }


 public interface IEventHandler<in T> where T : IDomainEvent
    {
        void Handle(T args);
    }

 public interface IEmailSender
    {
        void SendEmail(string emailAddress);
    }


 public interface IDomainEvent
    {
    }

public static class DomainEvents
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static IList<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>> Actions;

        public static void Register<T>(IEventHandler<T> callback) where T: IDomainEvent
        {
            if (Actions == null)
            {
                Actions = new List<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>>();
            }

            Actions.Add(callback);
        }

        public static void ClearCallbacks()
        {
            Actions = null;
        }

        public static void Raise<T>(T args) where T : IDomainEvent
        {
            if (Actions == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            foreach (IEventHandler<T> action in Actions)
            {
                (action).Handle(args);
            }
        }
    }


public class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler : IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>
    {
        public IEmailSender EmailSender { get; set; }

        public void Handle(CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent @event)
        {
            this.EmailSender.SendEmail(@event.Customer.EmailAddress);
        }
    }

public class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent : IDomainEvent
    {
        public CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent(Customer customer)
        {
            this.Customer = customer;
        }

        public Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }

public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }

        public bool HasUnpaidDues { get; set; }

        public void CheckUnpaidDues()
        {
            HasUnpaidDues = true;
            DomainEvents.Raise(new CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent(this));
        }
    }
```

Cheers.
Jas.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259104/ilist-using-covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-is-this-possible) should be a related issue.

Comment: @Vlad - Sorry to be a pain, but can you help me with a code example? This `covariance` and `contravariance` stuff is very confusing for me. How can I change my code so that it uses these techniques to solve my problem?

Comment: how is `IEventHandler` declared? Is it a system interface or your local one?

Comment: Hi there.I've just added the entire source code for my test app. Should have done that at the start - doh! :)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
The problem is that in order to have `IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>` to be in the list of `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>`s, we need `T` to be a covariant template parameter in `IEventHandler<T>` (which is declared as `IEventHandler<out T>`). However in order to allow the function `Handle(T arg)`, we need `T` to be *contravariant*. So strictly this way won't work. Imagine: if we really could insert an `IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>` into a list of `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>`s, than someone might try to call `Handle` with the argument of some type which derives from `IDomainEvent` but is not a `CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent`! This should be impossible to do.

The solution is that we don't need the exact type at `Register`, so we can keep a reference to a generic base interface. The implementation is here: http://ideone.com/9glmQ

Old answer is not valid, kept below for consistency.

---

Maybe you need to declare IEventHandler to accept T as a covariant type?

```
interface IEventHandler<in T> where T: IDomainEvent
{
    void Handle();
    // ...
}
```

Edit: surely `CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent` is an `IDomainEvent`, but you need `IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>` to be a `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>`. This is exactly what covariance does. In order to allow that, your template parameter in IEventhandler must be declared covariant (`<in T>` instead of just `<T>`).

Comment: Just tried that, but I get same compile issue with `Actions.Add()`. Hmm, this is a tricky one for me.

Comment: Hm, what is the error message? Could you please post your code of IEventHandler?

Comment: If it's covariant, it should be `out T` then.  (`in` is contravariant)

Comment: Okay, I see. Sorry, I don't have a compiler right now, so I cannot test the code myself. Could you please do the following: replace `Actions.Add(callback);` with `IEventHandler<IDomainEvent> callback2 = callback; Actions.Add(callback2);`?

Comment: @Jeff: oh, I should have tested it before posting. As I don't have a compiler now, I would ask the OP to test it for me.

Comment: @Vlad - Gave that a go, but got compiler warning. 'Cannot convert source type....' type of message.

Comment: @Jason: and what about changing `in` to `out`?

Comment: @Vlad - Cheers foe the effort, but when I run the code, I get an error on `Actions.Add`: "Unable to cast object of type 'CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler' to type 'IEventHandler`1[ConsoleApplication1.Program+IDomainEvent]'."}"

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for your Register method to be generic:

```
    public static void Register(IEventHandler<IDomainEvent> callback)
    {
        if (Actions == null)
        {
            Actions = new List<IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>>();
        }
        Actions.Add(callback);
    }
```

Comment: If I do that, then I get compile error on this line in my console application - `DomainEvents.Register(new CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler());`

Comment: what happens if you change ´class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler : IEventHandler<CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEvent>´ to ´class CustomerHasUnpaidDuesEventHandler : IEventHandler<IDomainEvent>´ ?